# How does relativistic Doppler effect conserve energy?

Tags: special-relativity, energy-conservation, doppler-effect

Say I have a laser traveling at the stationary observer at relativistic speed, so the laser wavelength gets blueshifted. To conserve total energy emitted, according to the observer, the laser emits smaller number of bluer photons. Is this how energy is conserved in special relativity settings?

Comment: Actually, the answer has nothing to do with relativity. Think about a much simpler situation: throw a baseball forward when you're standing in an airplane. Because the plane is moving quickly, the baseball will be released with an enormous speed and hence an enormous energy, even though you aren't trying any harder to throw it than you would on the ground! How is this compatible with energy conservation?

Comment: @knzhou in ground reference frame it's actually the plane propelling the thrower overcoming the recoil from throwing the ball. The ball experienced a small delta v at enormous base speed, and most of that added kinetic comes from the plane, not the throwers arm.

Comment: Yes, and in the relativistic Doppler shift the extra energy comes from the kinetic energy of the laser. The moving laser "throws" the photon forward with extra energy in exactly the same way as the baseball-on-airplane case. In the process the laser recoils a bit and loses some of its own kinetic energy, making up the difference.

Comment: > *To conserve total energy emitted, according to the observer, the laser emits smaller number of bluer photons.* No. Energy in different frames isn't the same number, so there is no need to explain any conservation when changing frames. Wavelength changes only when we change frames.

Comment: For massive bodies, what is conserved in different reference frames is the invariant mass - a mixture of energy and momentum. This is essentially a statement about four-velocity normalisation. For massless bodies, the same invariant is equal to zero, so instead of conservation law one can view it as a constraints that links energy and 3-monentum. Energy by itself is not invariant under boosts - it is not conserved